# responding to the model's property changes in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am having a model not in EF, but in plain text. I have to have the updated events handled for each of the model's properties so that i can log their changes.

Is there a way for this to be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) interface.

A simple example:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _myProperty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set 
        { 
            _myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like...

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(LogChange);

        model.MyProperty="apples";
        model.MyProperty="oranges";
        model.MyProperty="pears";
    }

    public static void LogChange(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.PropertyName + " has changed!");
        Console.WriteLine("New value: " 
                   + sender.GetType().GetProperty(args.PropertyName)
                     .GetValue(sender, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: is this possible to be used with the ASP.NET MVC 2 also. I am not using Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes you can use however you want. All you are doing is subscribing to an event which your model triggers when a property is updated. I've added a simple example above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. It was really useful. I was planning to implement this kind of feature.